# Extracting content of a file in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a file with a content like: (This is nmap output)

```
Nmap scan report for x.x.x.x
Host is up (0.12s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
| telnet-brute: 
|   Accounts
|     var1:var2
|   Statistics
|     Performed 5 guesses in 3 seconds, average tps: 1
|   
|_ ERROR: Too many retries, aborted ...

Nmap scan report for y.y.y.y
Host is up (0.17s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
| telnet-brute: 
|   Accounts
|     var3:var4
|   Statistics
|_    Performed 2 guesses in 13 seconds, average tps: 0

Nmap scan report for z.z.z.z
Host is up (0.19s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
| telnet-brute: 
|   Accounts
|     No valid accounts found
```

I want to extract this pattern:

```
x.x.x.x   var1:var2
y.y.y.y   var3:var4
```

What I tried is:

```
#!/bin/bash

NmapResult=$1

rm oooo
while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" == *Nmap* ]]; then
        OUT=$(grep "Nmap" -A6)
        if [[ "$OUT" == *valid* ]]; then
            continue
        else
            grep "Nmap" -A6 >> oooo
            echo
        fi
    fi
done < $NmapResult
```

But this is not true and not exactly what I want.

Could you possibly help me on this thread?

Thanks

Comment: Any time you find yourself writing a loop in shell to process text, you have the wrong approach.

Comment: Ok..How can I have right approach on these issues? Thank you

Comment: shell is an environment from which to call tools, with a language to let you sequence those calls. awk is a tool for general purpose text processing. So, the right approach is to just write a small awk script and call it from shell. I posted an answer. It works for the sample input you posted but if there's other formats of input, post samples of that too or tell us how to identify the fields you want output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{n=split($1,a,/ /); sub(/\| */,"",$7); print a[n], $7}' file
x.x.x.x var1:var2
y.y.y.y var3:var4
z.z.z.z No valid accounts found
```

or if you want to exclude the 3rd line of output, you might want:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '$7~/:/{n=split($1,a,/ /); sub(/\| */,"",$7); print a[n], $7}' file
x.x.x.x var1:var2
y.y.y.y var3:var4
```

Comment: Extraordinary... Thank you very much..I should push myself hard in order to learn `awk`  :)

Comment: Parden there is a problem here... My file is larger than what I put in question... This is about 2000 lines...I want sth that works for whole file

Comment: The script I posted doesn't care how many lines are in your file, it just works on blocks of text with blank lines between each block as shown in your sample input. If your real input doesn't follow the format of the sample input you posted, then update your question to better represent your real input.

Comment: Does that mean the script actually does work for your real input, or that you are going to update your question with new sample input that better represents your real input so we can try again?

Comment: Good. If you want to learn awk, get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins and simply do all text processing in awk for a while. Sometimes sed or grep are better choices, but awk can do whatever they can so by avoiding them in favor of awk for a while you'll get comfortable with the basics of awk. It's a VERY simple tool/language (essentially a tiny subset of C) once you get used to everything it does for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/^Nmap.* /{s///;h};/Accounts/{n;H;g;s/\n\|\s*/ /;/:/p}' file
```

This captures the required lines and fashions them into the required format.

Comment: thank you...very good answer...pardon if I want it just show me first column I mean just ips..what should I do?

Comment: @MortezaLSC just use: `sed -n 's/^Nmap.* //p' file`

Comment: No I mean the ips that have just accounts..I mean true ips